# Как передать ссылку на изображение из одного класса в другой?

Tags: java, android

Есть в layout изображение с `@+id/muse`, данные layout относится ко второму class'y, необходимо отправить ссылку на изображение в первый class.

Имеется BottomSheetDialog, в нем есть контейнер ImageView (то есть указан id и другое, но не стоит ссылки на drawable), мне необходимо объявить в class'e BottomSheetDialog этот id ImageView, чтобы потом в Основном классе при выполнении какого-нибудь условия применить.

К примеру, возьмем 10 картинок, закинем их в папку drawable, далее в Основном классе мы должны получить ссылку на ImageView в BottomSheetDialog, чтобы туда по очередности из Основного класса ставить эти 10 картинок за счет setImageResource.

Как передать ссылку на изображение из одного класса в другой?

Comment: если речь идет о классах - активити, то вы можете отправить ID изображения (как R.id.muse) через интент (это число типа int). Вообще нужно уточнить задачу: при каких особытиях нужно отправить этот id, зачем и что вообще должно происходить и тд. т.к. ID виджета из разметки одного активити в общем то совершенно бесполезен в другом. К изображениям в ресурсах вы можете обращаться непосредственно по их именам (как R.drawable.muse)

Comment: @pavlofff Имеется BottomSheetDialog, в нем есть контейнер ImageView (то есть указан id и другое, но не стоит ссылки на drawable), мне необходимо объявить в class'e BottomSheetDialog этот id ImageView, чтобы потом в Основном классе при выполнении какого-нибудь условия применить

Comment: то есть вы хотите из активити/фрагмента поместить в ImageView боттомшита на этой активити какую то картинку? для уточнения вопроса не пишите в комментарии, редактируйте вопрос кнопкой "править" под вопросом.

Comment: @pavlofff Именно, то есть возьмем 10 картинок, закинем их в папку drawable, далее в Основном классе мы должны получить ссылку на ImageView в BottomSheetDialog, чтобы туда по очередности из Основного класса ставить эти 10 картинок за счет setImageResource.